# How to deal with masks and shadowcatcher when compositing 3D elements over an image or video?

Tags: masking, compositing-nodes

I am trying to add 3-D dog ears to a human being in a real life video clip background.

I have to mask a portion of the persons hair over the 3-D model ears I created. The problem is I also have to add a shadow that is cast from the ears over the mask. It seems like every combination I try in the compositor has bad results.

This is the image of my compositor attempts
[image: This is the image of my compositor attempts]

This is the result where you can see some of the issues I'm having

[image: This is the result where you can see some of the issues I'm having]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The view layer for the shadow catcher should not have the ear, just the shadow catcher.

Comment: Also layers with alpha channel should be combined using the alpha over, and use the mask as fac. Also try multiplying the shadow catcher opacity.

Comment: @susu The shadow catcher layer requires the ear in order to cast the shadow doesn't it? Anytime I delete it it deletes it from the other view layer as well for some reason.      Also how do I multiply shadow catcher opacity, a gamma node?

Comment: You need the object to cast the shadow, but not the object itself on the layer. Multiply is one of the modes for the mix node.

Comment: @susu Thank you very much it is working now !

Comment: please write a complete answer in the answers section that details how you solved the question. Other users that have similar issues will appreciate learning from you.

Comment: @susu after a further render in full quality I am still having issues with the thumb mask rendering darker, I will write an answer once I can find why more issues are persisting !

Comment: Use the [edit] link at the bottom of your original post and add the information there at the end of the current text, not as comments. What have you changed in the node setup? (show images) What are you getting now as result?  What does the mask look like. It is easier to troubleshoot the results of nodes by using a viewer node and plug it at different stages of the node tree and see the  results of every particular operation, and not only the result of an equation with many variables. To help you better you have to help as well and share updates and changes in an active way.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't check a Mask option, but seems to me more natural to use an Object as a Mask and Shadow Catcher in once, so shadow follow the shape.

[image]

*Alpha Over* node seems to be working as expected.

[image]

[image]

---

Notes:

- Image in my 3Dviewport is an Empty object for a reference it doesn't influence a render. For the same effect (and probably easier) you can use image as bacgroud for camera (Camera Properties > Background Images) that can be video as well.
- With *Object ID* pass or *Cryptomatte* you can separate shadow and adjust if needed.

[image]